# Share data between 2 apps without internet using React Native

Tags: react-native, bonjour, zeroconf

I want to share data between apps offline. It is a few kb of JSON data. I tried using react-native-bonjour to transfer data. But In the library, I don`t see methods to send the data. I see only the methods to list the device connected to the same network.

Can someone help me here?